# How to write a basic SQL function to match values with a maximum and minimum range of values?

Tags: sql, statistics, p-value

If I have a data set like the following :

```
   type| min  | max
    -----------------
     a | 25   | 30
     b | 20   | 30
     c | 15   | 20
```

My goal is to match an input with a type, and to do that while taking into account that my types have overlapping values.

So let's say I have an input in my system that is 25, and I want to match my input to a type (either a, b, or c). My input is most likely b, since the average of the min and max of b is 25, and could possibly be a, but that is less likely. I've tried implementing this and have had no luck, and have also thought of using p-values, but am not sure how I can do it.

What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this fits your description:

```
select t.*
from t
where ? >= min and ? <= max
order by abs( ? - (max - min) / 2 )
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This identifies the ranges where the value matches.  It then chooses the range where the value is closest to the middle of the range.